# JavaScript event handling onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Following snippet:

```
<input type='text' name='text1' onkeyup='exec(this.value);'/>
```

The `exec()` method should not proceed if any of the following key is pressed on the textbox:

```
shift,
ctrl,
alt,
caps,
tab,
esc,
home,
etc
```

Is there a cross browser way without jQuery to do it?

Comment: e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey I tried which will throw an error when
I try it in IE v8.

Comment: You may want to look at https://github.com/nostrademons/keycode.js

Comment: there are keycodes you can use to determine what was pressed, have you tried any of those? i believe 16 is shift.

Comment: I'm currently writing a non-bloating workaround, but just stuck to time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461158/keycode-shortcut-each-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keycode shortcut each function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461158/keycode-shortcut-each-function)